# Dimensionality Reduction in Python (defining the variance threshold)

Tags: arrays, numpy, iteration, linear-algebra, python-3.6

Afternoon.  I'm having some trouble with my script.  Specifically, I'd like to keep the singular values and their corresponding eigenvectors when the sum of a subset of the eigenvalues is greater than .9*the sum of all the eigenvalues.  So far Iv'e been able to use a for loop and append function that creates a list of tuples that represent the singular values and eigenvectors.  However, when I try to nest an if statement within the for loop to meet the condition i break it.  here's my code.

```
o = np.genfromtxt (r"C:\Users\Python\Desktop\PCADUMMYDATADUMP.csv", delimiter=",")
o_m=np.matrix(o)

#We define the covariance matrix of our data accordingly  This is the mean centered data approx
#of the covariance matrix.  
def covariance_matrix(x):
    #create the mean centered data matrix.  this is the data matrix minus the matrix augmented from the vector that represents the column average
    m_c_d=x-np.repeat(np.mean(x, axis=0,), len(x), axis=0)
    #we compute the matrix operations here
    m_c_c=np.multiply(1/((len(m_c_d)-1)),np.transpose(m_c_d)*m_c_d)
    return m_c_c



#Define the correlation matrix for our mean adjsuted data matrix
def correlation_matrix(x):
    C_M = covariance_matrix(x)
    #matrix operation is diagonal(covariance_matrix)^-1/2*(covaraince_matrix)*diagonal(covariance_matrix)^-1/2
    c_m=fractional_matrix_power(np.diag(np.diag(C_M)),-1/2)*C_M*fractional_matrix_power(np.diag(np.diag(C_M)),-1/2)
    return c_m


def s_v_d(x):
    C_M=covariance_matrix(x)
    #create arrays that hold the left singular vectors(u), the right singular vectors(v), and the singular values (s)
    u,s,v=np.linalg.svd(C_M)
    #not sure if we should keep this here but this is how we can grab the eigenvalues which are the sqares of the singular values
    eigenvalues=np.square(s)

    singular_array=[]
    for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
        if np.sum(singular_array,axis=1) < (.9*np.sum(s)):
            singular_pairs=[s[i],v[:,i]]
            singular_array.append(singular_pairs)
        else:
            break

    return np.sum(s,axis=0)
```

specifically, consider the for and if loop after singular[array].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `singular_array` with its "mixed" scalar/vector elements is a bit more than `np.sum` can handle. I'm not 100% sure but aren't the variances the squares of the singular values? In other words shouldn't you be using your `eigenvalues` for the decision?

Anyway, here is a a non-looping approach:

```
part_sums = np.cumsum(eigenvalues)
cutoff = np.searchsorted(part_sums, 0.9 * part_sums[-1])
singular_array = list(zip(s[:cutoff], v[:, :cutoff]))
```

Change `eigenvalues` to `s` if you think it's more appropriate.

How it works:

`cumsum` computes the running sum over `eigenvalues`. Its  last element is therefore the total sum and we need only find the place where `part_sums` crosses 90% of that. This is what `searchsorted` does for us.

Once we have the cutoff all that remains is applying it to the singular values and vectors and to form the pairs using `zip`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user7351362 You're welcome. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Gah-is it? That's kind of a disappointment.  Thanks for providing an alternate method (works great-gonna have to learn how the zip and search functions work.

and yes-you're right on the squared values of the singualr values being the eigenvalues!  I actually thought i passed the squared values  in s_v_d but I'm a dummy haha.

*meant to edit my first reply as this but missed the five min cutoff time haha

Comment: I'm a little iffy on the search sorted function-mind explaining it and why you used it if you get a sec?

Comment: @user7351362 The `cumsum` in the line before creates a vector with e0, e0+e1, e0+e1+e2, ... etc.  Because the ei being variances are positive this is an upward sorted sequence. We want to know where it crosses 90% of the total.This is what `searchsorted` does. It takes the second argument where we have put the 90% and checks at which index it would fit in the first argument such that the combined sequence would still be sorted. So it tells us at which k e0+e1+....+ek crosses 90% e0+e1+...+en.

Comment: oh that's pretty powerful.  i'll def need to add it to my tool kit.  gonna try to track down some more numpy documentation.  much thanks.

as a last thing could you explain the significant of -1 in the argument of search sorted?

Comment: @user7351362 it just picks the last element of `part_sums` which is the total sum e0+e1+...+en